# Ejb deployment to WebLogic Server 11g

Tags: weblogic

I am using WebLogic 11g. I am using Eclipse. I have created a EJB project. This project is called 'remote-ejb'.
The bean class HelloWorldBean implements a remote interface HelloWorldBeanRemote with just on method; public String getName();

I then deployed this project as an application successfully.

I then created a second EJB project called cart-ejb. This project uses the bean from the first project. When I deploy this
project I get the following error:

Module named 'cart-ejb' failed to deploy. See Error Log view for more detail.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: beans.HelloWorldBeanRemote
Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you looked into dependency injection like `@javax.ejb.EJB`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24972/program.htm#EJBAD150 Have you attempted to include the same jar from the first project on your second project's classpath? Are you using JNDI lookups?

There is not enough information here to help... Please edit the question with more detail

Comment: It works if I use mappedName and the dependency injection. But I was trying to learn how to use remote interface without the use of mappedName and DI, in EJB 2.1 style.